# shopify login command failing with Errno::ENOENT | Shopify App CLI | Linux terminal

Tags: ruby, linux, shopify, shopify-app

I installed Shopify CLI per their how-to.  I have Ruby and Node.js installed and they both work.  I have not used shopify cli before now.  I used the command shopify login.  It opened a new tab in my already open browser (Chrome) and I got the Shopify login page.  I logged in, and then the page refreshed to just say Authentication Successful.  You may now close this window.  I did and went back to my terminal window.  It looked busy with something for a moment and then spit out the following:

```
This command ran with ID: 89449
Please include this information in any issues/report along with relevant logs
Traceback (most recent call last):
    43: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/bin/shopify:32:in `<main>'
    42: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/error_handler.rb:21:in `call'
    41: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/error_handler.rb:75:in `handle_abort'
    40: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/bin/shopify:33:in `block in <main>'
    39: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/core/entry_point.rb:23:in `call'
    38: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/core/monorail.rb:20:in `log'
    37: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/core/entry_point.rb:24:in `block in call'
    36: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/core/executor.rb:15:in `call'
    35: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:14:in `call'
    34: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:43:in `with_traps'
    33: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:55:in `twrap'
    32: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:44:in `block in with_traps'
    31: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:51:in `twrap'
    30: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in with_traps'
    29: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:15:in `block in call'
    28: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:35:in `with_logging'
    27: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui.rb:176:in `log_output_to'
    26: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:36:in `block in with_logging'
    25: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui/stdout_router.rb:169:in `with_id'
    24: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in with_logging'
    23: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in call'
    22: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/command.rb:25:in `call'
    21: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/commands/login.rb:34:in `call'
    20: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/commands/login.rb:78:in `select_organization'
    19: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/partners_api/organizations.rb:6:in `fetch_all'
    18: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/partners_api.rb:50:in `query'
    17: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/util.rb:172:in `retry_after'
    16: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/partners_api.rb:49:in `block in query'
    15: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/api.rb:36:in `query'
    14: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/api.rb:86:in `request'
    13: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/util.rb:172:in `retry_after'
    12: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/api.rb:56:in `block in request'
    11: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/api.rb:110:in `default_headers'
    10: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify_cli.rb:169:in `sha'
     9: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/git.rb:24:in `sha'
     8: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/git.rb:118:in `rev_parse'
     7: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/git.rb:112:in `exec'
     6: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/lib/shopify-cli/context.rb:493:in `capture3'
     5: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/system.rb:90:in `capture3'
     4: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.2/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/system.rb:194:in `delegate_open3'
     3: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:281:in `capture3'
     2: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:101:in `popen3'
     1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:213:in `popen_run'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:213:in `spawn': No such file or directory - git (Errno::ENOENT)
```

the path /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/ exists and there is a file in it called open3.rb.  In that file I see no reference to spawn.  I'm guessing that's actually a shopify cli or ruby command.  Maybe ruby can't see that path?  How to fix?

Comment: Strangely, or not, I upgraded to 2.3.0 and it's working.

shawn@AEROMINT:~$ shopify login --store=[shopname]
Opening in existing browser session.
[6228:6228:0100/000000.961038:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
Logged into store [shopname].myshopify.com in partner organization Veillon IT
shawn@AEROMINT:~$ 

Weird about the error though.  o.O  As long as it works!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but what you did it didn't solve the problem also every time i try to login again it throws me this

```
Opening in existing browser session.
[4663:4663:0100/000000.045394:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(378)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
┏━━ Error ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
┃ ✗ Invalid store provided (test-shopify.myshopify.com). Please make sure that the store belongs to your partner organization, and provide the store in the following format: my-store.myshopify.com
┃ 
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
```

UPDATE:

I saw this Git issue and it work smoothly

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/issues/1953

all you have to do is downgrade the Shopify-cli 2.9.0 to Shopify-cli 2.8.0

You can do this with this command `gem install shopify-cli -v '< 2.9.0'`